# How would a I format currency data to two decimal places?

Tags: java, floating-point, format

> "The bag contains " + numItems + " items. The retail cost of these
>   items is $" + getSubTotal() + ". The total cost of these items,
>   including tax, is $" + totalCost(numItems, finalTotal) + ".";

This is the return statement for a **toString** method.

Would I have to add it in the print line statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are concatenating strings, you can format the resulting value of those methods using

```
String.format("%.2f", someFloatValue);
```

Comment: String.format("%.2f", getSubTotal()) Got it working! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't build currency string yourself - use locale settings:

```
String output = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format( 123.45);
```

Result: 123,45 €

Comment: I should have worded my question differently. I just wanted my sub total and final total rounded to two decimal places. But thank you

Comment: If somewhere currency has 3 digits after dot, you should print it as %.3f, right? With DecimalFormat you don't think about it - just set right locale. The same thing is about currency sign.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll make note of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.format("%.2f",<your_total>)
```

will return the string representation of your double to 2 decimal places.